# How to find the deviated form of beta 1 in OLS

Tags: regression

How to find the deviated form of beta 1 in OLS

Y=β1+β2X+u

estimated β1=(ΣX^2ΣY-ΣXΣXY)/(nΣX^2-(ΣX)^2)

I do not know how to turn this part  (ΣX^2ΣY-ΣXΣXY)into deviated form.

I found that 
estimated β2=(nΣXY-ΣXΣY)/(nΣX^2-(ΣX)^2)=Σxy/Σx^2

x & y in deviated forms, ΣX=n(mean of X).

Comment: What do you mean by "deviated form of beta 1" ?. What is your goal ?

Comment: This means expressing estimated β1 by x & y, rather than X & Y. x=X-(mean of X), y=Y-(mean of Y).

Comment: I don´t know, if I really have understand your problem. But with your transformation I have calculated, that the (new) $\beta_1$ is 0.

Comment: Have you learnt OLS?

Comment: Yes, but I have never heard about the deviated form of a parameter. Is it a kind of transformation ? And could it be, that $\beta _1$ is just 0 ?

Comment: I guess it is possible, since deviated form of Y=β1+β2X+u is y=β2x+u. But the estimated β1 should have a symbolic deviated form, like (sth-sth)/(nΣX^2-(ΣX)^2)=0, right?

Comment: I think β2=(nΣXY-ΣXΣY)/(nΣX^2-(ΣX)^2) is a usual form, and β2=Σxy/Σx^2 is a deviated form.

Comment: Yes. I will post what I have calculated.

Comment: I have to leave now, and I will respond after 12 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression of $\beta_1$ is

$\beta_1=\Large{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2}}$

$x=X_i-\overline X$ and $y=Y_i-\overline Y$

Only the numerator of $\beta'_1$:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-\overline Y-\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)(Y_i-\overline Y)$

$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i=n\cdot \overline Y$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \overline Y=n\cdot \overline Y \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-\overline Y=0$

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-\overline Y=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2\cdot 0 =0$.

---

$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=n \cdot \overline X$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \overline X=n\cdot \overline X$

It follows, that $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)=0$.

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)(Y_i-\overline Y)=0$

In total $\beta'_1=0$